# gcc generate compile time error because of unabling to recognize __TIMESTAMP__ and some other defined build variable

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, embedded, gnu

I'm working with an existing example on eclipse & GCC based IDE for compiling my application for an embedded EFTPOS devices.
but in the below lines:

```
fprintf(stdout, "** Compilation date: %s \n", __TIMESTAMP__);
fprintf(stdout, "**** SDK release: %s \n", __SDK_RELEASE__);
fprintf(stdout, "**** ToolChain release: %s \n", __TOOLCHAIN_RELEASE__);
```

I received these compile time errors which seems compiler is unable to recognized these macros.

```
Symbol '__TIMESTAMP__' could not be resolved    main.c
Symbol '__SDK_RELEASE__' could not be resolved  main.c
Symbol '__TOOLCHAIN_RELEASE__' could not be resolved    main.c
```

If I try `fprintf(stdout, "** Compilation date: %s \n", __TIME__);` it is compiled successfully.
why compiler recognized `__TIME__`  macro but return error for `__TIMESTAMP__` ? also as you can see `__SDK_RELEASE__` and `__TOOLCHAIN_RELEASE__` are defined in build variables.

### [image: Image Link]

**EDIT:**
Thank for your reply and excuse me for my lacking in provided information.
In *C/C++ build ->setting->symbols*:

```
'__SDK_RELEASE__="${SDK_RELEASE}"'
'__TOOLCHAIN_RELEASE__="${TOOLCHAIN_RELEASE}"'
```

are defined,then `__SDK_RELEASE__` and`__TOOLCHAIN_RELEASE__` must be valid.Also I mean if `__TIME__` macro is valid `__TIMESTAMP__` must be do same,but it is not.

Comment: Did you try for example `SDK_RELEASE`? Just plain as it is defined. No idea why you pref- and suffix it with double underscores?

Comment: "*Also I mean if `__TIME__` macro is valid `__TIMESTAMP__` must be do same*" Why? From what exactly  do you conclude this?

Comment: No,I mean both of this macros must be worked.But I'm confused why one of them is worked and the other one is not.

Comment: I have no idea what _"In C/C++ build ->setting->symbols"_ does not being an Eclipse/CDT user, but does that create a linker symbol or a macro?  I suspect that is the real problem here.  Similarly does "build variables" create a linker symbol, an environment variable or a macro?  It is very unclear to see what is happening behind the IDE facade - better to post the verbatim raw build log to see exactly what is being passed to the compiler/linker and to determine whether these are compiler or linker errors.

Comment: Why do you think that `__TIME__` being defined implies that `__TIMESTAMP__` should be defined? That chain of logic is somewhat baffling. I suggest you need to define  `TIMESTAMP` (without the `__`), in terms of `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`, for examaple `#define TIMESTAMP __DATE__ " " __TIME__`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You defined `SDK_RELEASE` and `TOOLCHAIN_RELEASE` in build variables, so why should they be used with double underscores??..

Change your code to

```
fprintf(stdout, "**** SDK release: %s \n", SDK_RELEASE);
fprintf(stdout, "**** ToolChain release: %s \n", TOOLCHAIN_RELEASE);
```

About [`__TIME__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html), as you can see, macros are defined since [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) with "double underscores", that is why it works.

Form the [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.4.2.2 Predefined identifiers**
>
> Semantics
>
> 1 The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if,
>   immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> static const char **func**[] = "function-name";
>
> appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.<sup>72)</sup>
>
> **note.72** Since the name `__func__` is reserved for any use by the implementation (7.1.3), if any other
>   identifier is explicitly declared using the name `__func__`, the behavior is undefined.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

> **6.10.8.1 Mandatory macros**
>
> 1 The following macro names shall be defined by the implementation:
>
> `__DATE__` The date of translation of the preprocessing translation unit: a character
>   string literal of the form "Mmm dd yyyy", where the names of the
>   months are the same as those generated by the asctime function, and the
>   first character of dd is a space character if the value is less than 10. If the
>   date of translation is not available, an implementation-defined valid date
>   shall be supplied.
>
> `__FILE__` The presumed name of the current source file (a character string literal).
>
> `__LINE__` The presumed line number (within the current source file) of the current
>   source line (an integer constant).
>
> `__STDC__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate a conforming implementation.
>
> `__STDC_HOSTED__` The integer constant 1 if the implementation is a hosted
>   implementation or the integer constant 0 if it is not.
>
> `__STDC_VERSION__` The integer constant 201112L.
>
> `__TIME__` The time of translation of the preprocessing translation unit: a character
>   string literal of the form "hh:mm:ss" as in the time generated by the
>   asctime function. If the time of translation is not available, an
>   implementation-defined valid time shall be supplied.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

> **7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**
>
> 1 Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and
>   optionally declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated future library directions
>   subclause and identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as file
>   scope identifiers.
>
> — **All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
>   underscore are always reserved for any use.**
>
> — **All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers**
>   with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.
>
> [...]

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

---

As you can see the `__TIMESTAMP__` define is not in standard, so compilers are free to define or not define it: your current compiler does not.

Comment: @LPs: Thank you for reply,I also edit my question,I mean comiler must do same about __TIME__ and __TIMESTAMP__,not worked for one and return error for another one.

Comment: @MHD I added something about it to my answer.

Comment: @LPs: Thank you again,Although  I think this must be defined in my IDE,because I'm using it's own sample,and this sample is provided by IDE,but Seems you are right and there are some thing wrong about definition of this macro,Do you have any Idea about others? I tried SDK_RELEASE and __SDK_RELEASE__ and both does not compiled!WBR.

Comment: @MHD I think you defined your macro into the wrong setting. You should define it as _C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Symbols_